# Yellowbrick: is it possible to pass in different pairwise distance metrics for scoring methods

Tags: scikit-learn, yellowbrick

sklearn defines a large number of pairwise distance metrics for something like silhouette score: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html

For e.g. it can be initiated with any of these distance metrics:
`[‘cityblock’, ‘cosine’, ‘euclidean’, ‘l1’, ‘l2’, ‘manhattan’]`

However, say I go to use `KElbowVisualizer` from yellowbrick. I can pass in silhouette as the metric as follows:

`KElbowVisualizer(KMeans(), k=(4, 12), metric='silhouette')`

Which I assume uses the silhouette score default distance metric, 'euclidean'. Is it possible to run `KElbowVisualizer` using a different distance metric than the default?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was recently added to the development branch and should be released in v1.5.

https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/pull/1238